# Записать строку в 3 разных файлов

Tags: python

Дана строка 
пример: 'kcBZmaXiUOVScAnkPMlzmpOXIj'
Записать строку в 3 разных файлов (1-й символ в первый, второй во второй, третий в  третий и т.д)

Comment: "это сайт вопросов и ответов", таки где/в чем вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделите строку на три строчки и запишите в требуемые файлы. Для разделения можно воспользоваться slice notation (не знаю перевода устоявшегося). Так как строка это массив, то этот метод вполне подойдет.

Что такое slice notation. Допустим есть массив:

```
array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```

Можно взять элемент массива

```
a = array[0]
```

Тут а станет равно 10. Можно взять последовательность

```
a = array[0:3]
```

Тут а будет списком [10, 20, 30]. А можно взять не просто часть массива, а пройти по нему с некоторым шагом.

a = array[::3]

Тут берем каждый третий элемент и на выходе получаем список [10, 40]. В общем виде запись будет выглядеть так:

```
a[начало:конец:шаг]
```

- начало - это откуда начать итерацию
- конец - где остановиться
- шаг - шаг итерации

В общем, в вашем случае три нужных строки можно получить вот так:

```
incoming = 'kcBZmaXiUOVScAnkPMlzmpOXIj' 

out1 = incoming[0::3]
out2 = incoming[1::3]
out3 = incoming[2::3]
```